# Как организовать проверку кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Есть вот такой код:

```
password = self.password+'\n'
password = password.encode()
# Если нет, копируем файл, проверяем на ошибки, и перезапускаем bind
try: 
   copy_file = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'cp',\
                                 '/home/bel/new_parser_bel/zones.blacklisted', '/etc/bind/zones/'],\
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=bytes(password))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
  log.error('FAIL to copy', exc.returncode, exc.output)
```

Нужно сделать проверку на выходные данные(stderr, stdout)

К примеру:

```
if len(copy_file.stderr)>0:
    log.error("Fail to copy", copy_file.stderr)
    sys.exit(0)
if len(copy_file.stdout)>0:
    log.info(copy_file.stdout)
```

Но когда я обращаюсь к copy_file, пишет что это tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, надо просто посмотреть документацию по [subprocess.Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data
> will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.

Так что нужно использовать такой код, прямо как в документации написано:

```
outs, errs = subprocess.Popen(...).communicate(...)
```

Тогда в `errs` будет вывод ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и ссылку на документацию.